# Does SGE check for the output of the dependency before launching a dependent job?

Tags: parallel-processing, cluster-computing, qsub, sungridengine

When running

```
qsub -N jobName -hold_jid 435 sge_script.sh
```

Does SGE check whether the job 435 finished successfully before launching this one? 
If yes, if the output is such that the job 435 failed and must be automatically relaunched, is the dependency changed to the the job id?

Comment: The question is a bit unclear.  Grid Engine does check the job exit code.  There is special behavior for exit code 99 (requeue) and 100 (prevent dependent jobs from executing).

Comment: Yes, I saw about exit codes 99 and 100 in the refs. But I am unsure of what happens with the dependencies. I will try to clarify editing the question.